# Split outcome from batch file to multi different sheets in Excel

Tags: batch-file, cmd, teradata

I'm facing an issue, I'm working with Teradata and BTEQ.

My queries (over 40) are stored in differents txt file to be triggered by a .bat file every night.

I would like to export the outcome in multi differents sheets from an excel file depending the relevant query.

Do you have any idea to complete this following code:

Ex query 1

```
  .logon UID/PASS;
  .set width 32767;
  .set separator ",";
  .export file = c:\chris\toto1.xls;  maybe this row should indicate the sheet ?
   select top 10 * from table1;
  .export reset;
```

I'm novice and interested by the possibilities of BTEQ/batch file. So if you have any documentation.

Thanks in advance
Christophe

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Compo "so if you have any documentation" is unfortunate wording.  However, if you read the question I believe the OP is asking for a solution to a specific code problem and not an off site resource.

Comment: Regardless of the unfortunate use of the wording requesting documentation, the OP is specifically asking for ideas to complete the code, not for help fixing a specific code problem, which is also off topic; 'Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].'

Comment: BTEQ (or TPT, etc) cannot build an XLS/XLSX file.  It can only build a CSV.  You'll need to use a different scripting language to combine multiple CSVs into a Excel file with multiple tabs.  I'd look at VB Script or Powershell maybe?

Comment: @Compo Thanks.  I think your second comment is much clearer and more relevant

Comment: You will need to export into multiple CSVs, as suggested by Andrew, and then tie these files into a single XML, which is a way to compile a multi-sheet Excel document.